# Remove repetitions in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a function that takes a linked list of items and deletes all repetitions from the list. For some reason, when I run a linked list in the function it only removes one of the repeated items.

Here's my code:

```
#include "node1.h";
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace main_savitch_5;

void noRepeat(node* head_ptr){
    for (node* i = head_ptr; i != NULL; i = i->link()){
        for (node* j = i->link(); j != NULL; j = j->link()){

            if (i->data() == j->data()){
                list_remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
}

void list_print(node * head_ptr){
    //Start at the head pointer and loop through the linked list
    for (node* i = head_ptr; i != NULL; i = i->link()){
        //Print out current element
        cout<<i->data()<<" ";
    }
    //New line
    cout<<""<<endl;
}

int main(){
    node* one = new node(5);
    node* two = new node(3, one);
    node* three = new node(5, two);
    node* four = new node(6, three);
    node* five = new node(3, four);
    noRepeat(five);
    list_print(five);
}
```

**Implemented functions:**

```
//Receives current node data
value_type data() const { return data_field; }

//Receives link
node *link() { return link_field; }
```

**List remove function**

```
void list_remove(node *previous_ptr) {
        node *remove_ptr;

        remove_ptr = previous_ptr->link();
        previous_ptr->set_link(remove_ptr->link());
        delete remove_ptr;
    }
```

When I first run my code, the noRepeat function takes in the head pointer which is the five, and tries to remove all duplicates. Afterwards, the list is printed out. The printed out list is: 3 6 5 3 but it should be 3 6 5, why is 5 being deleted but the three isn't?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I want to understand why it's wrong though, specifically my noRepeat function. Is there any noticeable errors? Or does it look like I implemented it properly?

Comment: the least you can do is at least show your list_remove() function, you can't really expect us to figure out what you are doing, when we can't even see your entire implementation.

Comment: Nearly all of your linked list implementation is buried in code we cannot see, and cannot therefore analyze regarding how it relates to *your* code.Ex: suppose you want to remove the *last* element in your list. Then `list_remove(j);` is called. What is `j` after that? We have no way of knowing; *you do*. Proceed to the increment step of your for-j loop, which does this: `j = j->link()`. What is `j` pointing to *before* that is invoked, and more important, *after* ? *You* have the source. *You* can debug this. *We* cannot.

Comment: @VikashB I have included the list_remove() function

Comment: Nope, still can't do it, your code isn't complete, can't compile/debug in my pc, i don't want to guess what your link() and set_link() functions do, please read above comments and provide a Minimal Complete Verifiable example that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the inner loop

```
    for (node* j = i->link(); j != NULL; j = j->link()){

        if (i->data() == j->data()){
            list_remove(j);
        }
```

You're calling the function `list_remove` with the node `j`, meaning that this is the node you wish to remove (at least according to the logic of your double loop).

However, the function actually takes the *preceding* node to the node to be removed, and removes the *next* node. Asides from the logic in the function, you can already see it in

```
void list_remove(node *previous_ptr) {
```

In your example, the next node of 3 is null, so nothing is actually removed.

Comment: For some reason when I use your code, the program runs but then stops working and exits. The issues that are making it do that is the second loop where it says: j->link() != NULL and the if statement where it says: j->link()->data()

Comment: @user2896120 Well, that's the point where I have to join the other commentors in that you really didn't provide enough to run your code. I'll erase my suggestion (which I can't build/run anyway), but the issue causing your last 3 not to be erased, is the one I explained.